# How to add height and width to images on a page(using WP Bakery) to improve Google's CLS score?

Tags: plugins, images, google

In Google's page speed insights my CLS Score for some pages is low because of the following.

"Image elements do not have explicit width and height" Set an explicit width and height on image elements to reduce layout shifts and improve CLS. [Learn more](https://web.dev/optimize-cls/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=lr#images-without-dimensions).

I have added a regenerate thumnbnails plugin and also using very specific image URL in the page builder //www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/myimage-x-4-768x258.jpg where the image is to be displayed. Even then the page speed insight shows all the images under the same section. That it needs width and height.

Please let me know if you have any tips.

Comment: The built in WordPress blocks and functions include these attributes, so if a particular theme or plugin is not adding them, that's something you will need to ask the developer about, as third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: yes, makes sense. Thank you.